# hiding and showing divs with Jquery, with radio buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, forms

I want to hide the divs with the radio buttons until they're title is clicked on but something is,'t working because now I can't get them to show when their title is clicked on. 
Any help is appreciated.
SPIKE``

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="generator" content="CoffeeCup Web Editor (www.coffeecup.com)">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="keywords" content="">
    <title></title>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link href="mebbe2.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

    <style>
        body {
            background-color: #7094B8;
        }

        .container {
            position: relative;
            left: 24%;
        }

        h1 {
            align-text: center;
        }

        #butt {
            display: block;
            background-color: #e5eecc;
            height: 230px;
            width: 500px;
            padding: 3px;
            border: solid 2px #c3c3c3;
        }

        p {
            font-weight: bold;
            font-size: 22px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div id="select">
        <h1>Select Your Preferred Search</h1>

        <p>Click on your choice of search method.</p>
        <button id="communities">Communities Served</button>
        <br>
        <button id="specialties">Therapeutic Specialties</button>
        <br>
        <button id="insurance">Insurance Accepted</button>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $(".special,.commune,.insure").hide();
            });
        </script>

        <script>
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $("#communities").click(function () {
                    $(".select, .special, .insure").hide();
                });
                $("#show").click(function () {
                    $(".commune").show();
                });
            });
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $("#specialties").click(function () {
                    $(".select,.insure,.commune").hide();
                });
                $("#show").click(function () {
                    $(".special").show();
                });
            });
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $("#insurance").click(function () {
                    $(".select,.special,.commune").hide();
                });
                $("#show").click(function () {
                    $(".insure").show();
                });
            }); </script>
    </div>
    <div class="commune" id="butt"><h3>Choose Your Community</h3>

        <form action="input">
            <input type="radio" name="common" value="caucasion">Caucasion<br>
            <input type="radio" name="common" value="hispanic">Hispanic<br>
            <input type="radio" name="common" value="carribean">Carribean<br>
            <input type="radio" name="common" value="africanAmerican">African-American<br>
            <input type="radio" name="common" value="male">Male<br>
            <input type="radio" name="common" value="female">Female<br>
            <input type="radio" name="common" value="professional">Professional<br>
            <input type="radio" name="common" value="lGBT">LGBT<br>
            <input type="radio" name="common" value="youth">Youth
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="special" id="butt">
        <h3>Choose Your Specialty</h3>

        <form action="input">
            <input type="radio" name="spec" value="groups">Groups<br>
            <input type="radio" name="spec" value="couples">Couples<br>
            <input type="radio" name="spec" value="abuse">Abuse<br>
            <input type="radio" name="spec" value="addictions">Addictions<br>
            <input type="radio" name="spec" value="loss">Loss<br>
            <input type="radio" name="spec" value="depression">Depression<br>
            <input type="radio" name="spec" value="family">Family Conflict<br>
            <input type="radio" name="spec" value="esteem">Self Esteem
        </form
    </div>
    <div class="insure" id="butt">
        <h3>Choose Your Insurance </h3>

        <form action="input">
            <input type="radio" name="insur" value="harvard">Harvard Pilgrim<br>
            <input type="radio" name="insur" value="blueCross">Blue Cross and Blue Shield<br>
            <input type="radio" name="insur" value="tufts">Tufts<br>
            <input type="radio" name="insur" value="healthNet">Health Net<br>
            <input type="radio" name="spec" value="loss">Loss<br>
            <input type="radio" name="insur" value="humana">Humana<br>
            <input type="radio" name="spec" value="loss">Loss<br>
            <input type="radio" name="insur" value="cigna">Cigna
        </form>

    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yes, your code is very hard to read at the moment.

Comment: This is terrible. Not only is the formatting bad, the HTML is extremely badly written (double IDs, missing or extra closing tag, superfluous `>` etc.). For the ones who want to play with it: I made a fiddle where I started to play with it, but I gave up. This is a waste of our time. http://jsfiddle.net/Xqm77/

Comment: I edited the HTML so that we can at least read it easier.

Comment: I suppose that this explains it: `<meta name="generator" content="CoffeeCup Web Editor (www.coffeecup.com)">`

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing you want this. http://jsfiddle.net/Xqm77/1/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".special,.commune,.insure").hide();
    $("#communities").click(function () {
        $(".select, .special, .insure").hide();
        $(".commune").show();
    });
    $("#specialties").click(function () {
        $(".select,.insure,.commune").hide();
        $(".special").show();
    });
    $("#insurance").click(function () {
        $(".select,.special,.commune").hide();
        $(".insure").show();
    });
});
```

**However**, you can write this much shorter when you add a little bit of HTML. Add a data-attribute to every button, and use that attribute to know which section to show. Like so:

```
<button id="communities" data-show="commune">Communities Served</button>
```

By doing so, you can use a single click function. See it in action here: http://jsfiddle.net/Xqm77/2/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".container > div:not(#select)").hide();
    $("#select button").click(function() {
        var $this = $(this),
            toShow = $this.data("show");
        $(".container > div:not(#select)").hide().filter("."+toShow).fadeIn("slow");
    });
});
```

Comment: I'm sorry it's so messy, I took a 3 month break from classwork when our kid was born early. I appreciate all the comments. Thanks, Bram. That got it working.